# Continuous Html5 audio .play() with only 1st time trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, html5-audio

I want play the continuous sound sequence by doing function call fallback with `.play()` in each of the function to play the sound 1 by 1.

**The funniest thing is:** 
**There will be different sound performance each time playing on my iPad device.**
**Sometime play the audio 3 times, sometimes 4 times, even only 1 times!**

**The "Sudden stop problem" in the iPad only, it is fine on my Google Chrome.**

It is not an auto-play problem of iPad I guess coz I have already trigger in the 1st time...

Please take a look and have a test on iPad perhaps and please help...

Html - Body:

```
<audio id="html5soundtag"> 
    <source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio> 
<a href="javascript://" onClick="playhtml5sound1('1.mp3')">aaaa</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var audioPath ="";

var audioElement = document.getElementById('html5soundtag');

function playhtml5sound1(filename){ 
    audioPath = filename;
    audioElement.src = audioPath;
    audioElement.src = audioPath
    audioElement.load()
    audioElement.play();
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended",soundcallback1);
};
var soundcallback1 = function (){
    alert("1st");
    audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",soundcallback1);
    playhtml5sound2("1.mp3");
}


function playhtml5sound2(filename){
    audioPath = filename;
    audioElement.src = audioPath;
    audioElement.src = audioPath
    audioElement.load();        
    audioElement.play();
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended",soundcallback2);

};
var soundcallback2 = function (){
    alert("2nd");
    audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",soundcallback2);
    playhtml5sound3("1.mp3");
}

function playhtml5sound3(filename){
    audioPath = filename;
    audioElement.src = audioPath;
    audioElement.src = audioPath
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended",soundcallback3);

};var soundcallback3 = function (){
    alert("3rd");
    audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",soundcallback3);
    playhtml5sound4("1.mp3");
}

function playhtml5sound4(filename){
    audioPath = filename;
    audioElement.src = audioPath;
    audioElement.src = audioPath
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();

    audioElement.addEventListener("ended",soundcallback4);

};var soundcallback4 = function (){
    alert("4th");
    audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",soundcallback4);
    playhtml5sound5("1.mp3");
}

function playhtml5sound5(filename){
    audioPath = filename;
    audioElement.src = audioPath;
    audioElement.src = audioPath
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();

    audioElement.addEventListener("ended",soundcallback5);

};var soundcallback5 = function (){
    alert("5th");
    audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",soundcallback5);
    playhtml5sound6("1.mp3");
}

function playhtml5sound6(filename){
    alert("This is End. " + filename);
}
```

Comment: Do you use 1.mp3 only? with 6 different callbacks? did you intend to play 1.mp3, 2.mp3 etc?

Comment: yes, for the testing I only use single sample sound "1.mp3" because right now my problem is the callback will suddenly die(stop) when running on the ipad...and each time different on the time of "dead"!   For example, there will be only 2 callback run and for next time, it run completely, then next time just run 1 callback...There are just different after refreshing the Web page...

Comment: Please, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)
There is absolutely no need to have 5 pretty much identical functions, not to mention the event listener juggling.

Comment: What is your iPad generation and which iOS are you running?

Comment: Sorry Cerbrus: It is really because the callback will stop randomly each time so I added them for testing, sorry for the long code...

Comment: My version is 5.1.1, The new iPad(3)

Comment: iOS5.1.1 browser is very slow on iPad3. I know there's a big doubt to update it to 6.0.1, but the browser in iOS6 is much faster (yep, I tested iPad3 on iOS5.1.1, 6.0 and 6.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem, and at very least, it will keep your code more maintainable:

```
var audioPath = "";
var audioElement = document.getElementById('html5soundtag');

var soundIndex = 0;
var sounds = ["1.mp3","2.mp3","3.mp3","4.mp3","5.mp3"]

function playhtml5sound(){
    if(soundIndex < sounds.length){
        audioPath = sounds[soundIndex];
        audioElement.src = audioPath;
        audioElement.load()
        audioElement.play();
        soundIndex++;
    }else{
        audioElement.removeEventListener("ended",playhtml5sound);
        alert("Last sound ended!")
    }
};

audioElement.addEventListener("ended", playhtml5sound);
```

```html
<a href="javascript://" onClick="playhtml5sound()">aaaa</a>
```

Each time the music finishes, `playhtml5sound()` is executed, playing the next sound.
If the last sound is played, remove the event listener, and alert the ending.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer, but the code is too large for showing in a comment.

I suggest you add the following code to your script and check the console log for any other events than ended (for example stalled or error events). I tested in iPad and iPod, both work ok, maybe you have errors due to networking.

```
var media_events = new Array();
function audioattachevents(selector) {
    media_events["abort"] = 0;
    media_events["error"] = 0;
    media_events["mousewheel"] = 0;
    media_events["blur"] = 0;
    media_events["focus"] = 0;
    media_events["pause"] = 0;
    media_events["canplay"] = 0;
    media_events["formchange"] = 0;
    media_events["play"] = 0;
    media_events["canplaythrough"] = 0;
    media_events["forminput"] = 0;
    media_events["playing"] = 0;
    media_events["change"] = 0;
    media_events["input"] = 0;
    media_events["progress"] = 0;
    media_events["click"] = 0;
    media_events["invalid"] = 0;
    media_events["ratechange"] = 0;
    media_events["contextmenu"] = 0;
    media_events["keydown"] = 0;
    media_events["readystatechange"] = 0;
    media_events["dblclick"] = 0;
    media_events["keypress"] = 0;
    media_events["scroll"] = 0;
    media_events["drag"] = 0;
    media_events["keyup"] = 0;
    media_events["seeked"] = 0;
    media_events["dragend"] = 0;
    media_events["load*"] = 0;
    media_events["seeking"] = 0;
    media_events["dragenter"] = 0;
    media_events["loadeddata"] = 0;
    media_events["select"] = 0;
    media_events["dragleave"] = 0;
    media_events["loadedmetadata"] = 0;
    media_events["show"] = 0;
    media_events["dragover"] = 0;
    media_events["loadstart"] = 0;
    media_events["stalled"] = 0;
    media_events["dragstart"] = 0;
    media_events["mousedown"] = 0;
    media_events["submit"] = 0;
    media_events["drop"] = 0;
    media_events["mousemove"] = 0;
    media_events["suspend"] = 0;
    media_events["durationchange"] = 0;
    media_events["mouseout"] = 0;
    media_events["timeupdate"] = 0;
    media_events["emptied"] = 0;
    media_events["mouseover"] = 0;
    media_events["volumechange"] = 0;
    media_events["ended"] = 0;
    media_events["mouseup"] = 0;
    media_events["waiting"] = 0;

    for (key in media_events) {
      selector.bind(key, function (e, data) {
        console.log(e.type);
      });
    }
}

audioattachevents($('#html5soundtag'));
```

Especially for those who want the short notation:

```
media_events = {"abort":0,"error":0, "mousewheel":0, "blur":0, "focus":0, "pause":0, 
   "canplay":0, "formchange":0, "play":0, "canplaythrough":0, "forminput":0, 
   "playing":0, "change":0, "input":0, "progress":0, "click":0, "invalid":0, 
   "ratechange":0, "contextmenu":0, "keydown":0, "readystatechange":0,       
   "dblclick":0, "keypress":0, "scroll":0, "drag":0, "keyup":0, "seeked":0, 
   "dragend":0, "load*":0, "seeking":0, "dragenter":0, "loadeddata":0, 
   "select":0, "dragleave":0, "loadedmetadata":0, "show":0, "dragover":0, 
   "loadstart":0, "stalled":0, "dragstart":0, "mousedown":0, "submit":0, 
   "drop":0, "mousemove":0, "suspend":0, "durationchange":0, 
   "mouseout":0, "timeupdate":0, "emptied":0, "mouseover":0, 
   "volumechange":0, "ended":0, "mouseup":0, "waiting":0}
```

Comment: Thanks bart, I will try this now!  BTW, Do you mean you can show the alert of "This is End." everytime the same?

Comment: Use a array if you need to store a load of strings. Or if you _have_ to use a object, at least use the short notation: `media_events = {"abort":0, "error":0, etc...}`. Actually, you are initializing the object as `var media_events = new Array();`
That won't work. You can't set `key / value` properties of arrays. Your array is empty.

Comment: @Cerbrus agree, but then I need to change existing code, so I just use copy & paste. For user1900121: The above is just for testing if you get any other events that may give you a reason why the audio aborts. This can be for example if the network is stalling, retransmitting and if your WiFi in the iPad sucks (which can happen)

Comment: "Change existing code"? It's 2 minutes of work to convert that non-working object notation of yours to a proper array.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Non working? Did you test it? I guess you're the one downvoting. And YES i do need the OBJECT because in my code I also use something to count the number of events!

Comment: There is nothing counting anything in that code.
And do you know why it doesn't work?
You're trying to add properties to a `array`. JavaScript will silently fail when you do that. In the end, the array will be empty, and you won't be adding any event listeners to the `audio` element.
Also, [yes, I did test it.](http://jsfiddle.net/VA2qK/1/)

Comment: As I got the example code from [www.w3.org](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html), you are more or less claiming they are wrong.

Comment: Okay, apparently I was wrong about JavaScript not adding the properties to the array object, the console just didn't show them.
That doesn't take away the fact that it's bad practice to declare a variable as `array`, then use it as object, however.
Where exactly did you grab that array/object from? do you have a link?
I don't believe w3 would go against their own standards.